# Ckeditor- heroku broken after rails 4 upgrade

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor, asset-sync

Can't seem to figure out why ckeditor no longer works on heroku.
It works fine on my local machine.

**UPDATE: works without the asset_sync gem when assets are hosted on heroku - but does not work with it.**

Errors:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in config.js:1
ckeditor cannot find config.js, the < is an opening tag of the 404 not found page
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)

Appreciate any help I can get.

Ckeditor gem, Heroku, Rails 4, **asset_sync**

application.js

```
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require ckeditor/config
```

gemfile - version 4.0.7

```
gem "ckeditor"
```

appplication.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)
config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets
config.assets.precompile += %w(ckeditor/*)
```

production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

Comment: read this https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/333 hope it will help you

Comment: It works if assets are hosted on Heroku - but I'm using the asset_sync gem and I can't get that to work...... removed asset_sync and tested - and it works - so now need to figure out how to put that back in -Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works when the asset version is updated

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#include-customized-ckeditor_basepath-setting I have fixed loading CKEditor assets with asset_sync on Heroku by including (before ckeditor/init) a ckeditor/basepath.js.erb:

```
<%
  base_path = File.join Rails.application.config.action_controller.asset_host || '',
                    Rails.application.config.assets.prefix,
                   '/ckeditor/'
%>

(function() {
  if (typeof window['CKEDITOR_BASEPATH'] === "undefined" || window['CKEDITOR_BASEPATH'] === null) {
    window['CKEDITOR_BASEPATH'] = '<%= base_path %>';
  }
}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work when the ASSET Version is updated in the system.

Comment: could you explain, what do you mean by updating `asset`?